# QWebException: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position

Tags: python, linux, node.js, centos, odoo

I have Installed `odoo9`on my server (CentOS). When I try to run the application I am getting an error

> QWebException: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 208946: ordinal not in range(128)

I don't have any idea on this issue. Anyone have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a 7 bit code, which means that you cannot use codes above (and including) `0x80` to `0xff`  (they are undefined in ASCII code)  It has characters only in the range `0x00` to `0x7f`.

Perhaps you'll need to switch to `iso-8859-*` codes (or even better) to `UTF`.

The command:

```
man ascii
```

will show you the complete `ASCII` character set.

Do some googling with the keywords I have used in the last paragraph and you'll get more information.